# No ejecuta, el programa dejo de funcionar

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++

> Escribir un programa que calcule y visualice la media aritmética de un vector de 10 elementos
> numéricos, utilizando una variable puntero que apunte a dicho vector, (por favor ayuda, es en C para DEV c++)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int v[10], *pv=NULL;
int i;
int sumatoria;
float media;
for (i=0; i<10;i++){
    printf("Introducir el elemento o numero:  ");
    scanf("%d",(pv+i));
    sumatoria+=*(pv+i);
}
media=sumatoria/10;
printf ("El promedio o media es igual a= %f", media);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Tu programa NUNCA pero NUNCA funcionará porque `pv` SIEMPRE apunta a `NULL`, esto ocasiona un [segment fault](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso). Debes hacer esta asignación: `pv = v`.

Comment: Esto es C, por que pones la etiqueta de [tag:c++]??

Comment: Yo veo etiqueta `dev-c++`, no `c++`. La variable `sumatoria` también debe ser float, y debería inicializarse a 0 antes de empezar a sumarle.

Answer (score 3):

Lee tu código un momento.

Estás usando el puntero `pv` que está apuntando a una dirección inválida. Tan solo tienes que pasarle una dirección.

En tu caso intuyo que quieres que sea el arreglo. Recordemos que estos decaen en punteros, por lo que no es necesario el uso del operador `&`. Puedes hacerlo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Corrección
    int v[10], *pv = v;

    // Corrección
    int sumatoria = 0;
    float media = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
        printf("Introducir el elemento o numero:  ");
        scanf("%d",(pv+i));
        sumatoria+=*(pv+i);
    }

    // Corrección 
    media=sumatoria/10.f;
    printf ("El promedio o media es igual a= %f", media);

    return 0;
}
```

No olvides que en C, al menos uno de los dos operandos debe ser de tipo flotante para obtener un resultado con decimales.

Tu estabas usando 2 `int`s, por lo que si el promedio te debería dar, digamos, `6,5`, cuando imprimas la variable descubrirás que tendrás `6` en su lugar. También está corregido en el ejemplo que te acabo de dar.

**Actualización:** También deberías considerar inicializar todas tus variables a fin de evitar comportamientos inesperados. Puedes ver que en el ejemplo lo hago asignándoles el valor 0 antes de comenzar a usarlas.

Comment: Inicializar `sumatoria` sería una buena idea. Saludos.

Comment: Se me pasó por alto. Gracias.